# CAKEPHP 3.X create query with matching

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I try to fetch some results,

1) the results that contain the keywords and are listed in the 'Assimg' table

2) the results that contain the keywords and contain some predefined 'initialen'

I can get the results separate, biut not in one query.

```
 public function premsearchlocalequery($id, $q)
{

    $query = $this->find('all');


    if ($q != null) {
        $mysqlsearchtype = " IN BOOLEAN MODE";
        $query->where('MATCH(Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description) AGAINST(:search ' . $mysqlsearchtype . ')')->matching('Assimg');
        $query->bind(':search', $q);

    }



    if ($q != null) {
        $mysqlsearchtype = " IN BOOLEAN MODE";
        $query->Orwhere(['Premsearches.initialen IN' => $id, 'MATCH(Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description) AGAINST(:search ' . $mysqlsearchtype . ')']);
        $query->bind(':search', $q);
    }

    $query->order(['Premsearches.ID' => 'desc']);
    return $query;


}
```

returns this sql:

```
...
    FROM 
  `archief` `Premsearches` 
  INNER JOIN `archief_client_ass_image` `Assimg` ON `Premsearches`.`ID` = (`Assimg`.`photo_ID`) 
WHERE 
  (
    MATCH(
      Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description
    ) AGAINST('+keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    OR (
      `Premsearches`.`initialen` in ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc') 
      AND MATCH(
        Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description
      ) AGAINST('+keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  `Premsearches`.`ID` desc 
LIMIT 
  100 OFFSET 0
```

but I want it to be something like this this sql:

```
   ...
        FROM 
      `archief` `Premsearches` 
      INNER JOIN `archief_client_ass_image` `Assimg` ON `Premsearches`.`ID` = (`Assimg`.`photo_ID`) 
    WHERE 
      (
        MATCH(
          Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description
        ) AGAINST('+keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
   ANDWHERE 
  (
    `Premsearches`.`initialen` in ('LVA', 'JDB', 'IDC_81') 
    AND MATCH(
      Premsearches.keywords, Premsearches.description
    ) AGAINST('+jodenbuurt' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ) 
    ORDER BY 
      `Premsearches`.`ID` desc 
    LIMIT 
      100 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: `orWhere` has been deprecated as of CakePHP 3.5. This may be an example of the kind of query that didn't work reliably with it and thus led to this decision. You may need to build an array of the conditions and then call `->where(['OR' => $condition_array])`.

Comment: Tnx, I did'nt know that. How can I combine ->where and ->matching?

Comment: I don't have any experience combining query expressions in such a way, but I'd guess that it might work to create the expression objects for each piece, put them in an array and call it like I did above.